# Umbraco - Incorrect link to document when useDomainPrefixes = true

Tags: hyperlink, umbraco, hostname

(To make this simpler - I've re-posted the first part of this question as a separate question, which has now been answered:)

[Umbraco - Incorrect alternative link to document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709921/umbraco-incorrect-alternative-link-to-document)

Here's the full, original question:

---

On our website, we have the following structure:

```
sitename
  -Global
    -English
  -UK
    -English
```

for the Global > English page, the links to the page are showing as:

**Link to document**

/global/en/

**Alternative Links**

```
http://english
```

so the 'Link to document' is correct, but the alternative link isn't.  On the UK > English page, I just get the correct 'Link to document'
On our development version, I've just turned on the useDomainPrefixes = true option in the umbracoSettings.config of of the site, and I've added a hostname for the top level 'sitename' node.  Now I get the following as page links for the Global > English page:

**Link to document**

```
http://english/
```

**Alternative Links**

```
http://hostname/http://english/

http://english
```

I get the correct links for the UK > English page, showing the correct hostname in the URL like this:

**Link to document**

```
http://hostname/global/en/
```

I've tried re-publishing the entire root node (sitename), however I get an unusual timeout error.  I've increased the timeout for the app pool, and for the session and the umbraco timeout in the web.config, however this is a different error probably related to the proxy server contacting the web server.

Is republishing the entire site the only fix?  I've tried only publishing the sitename > Global node, which completes successfully, but doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: You probably need to post these as two separate questions, just to keep it simpler as I assume the first part of the question (without domain prefixes enabled) is the main problem you are facing?

Comment: Personally, I would create a new, very basic Umbraco instance with one doc type and a handful of pages replicating this top-level structure. It should take 15 minutes to do. You will be able to minimise the fuss of publishing and see clearly whether you get the same results. I assume you are using the `umbracoUrlAlias` property to get the /en/ path, so this should also be picked up in the "alternative links" field as well. I would also avoid `useDomainPrefixes=true` unless you have to as it will just complicate things.

Comment: Hi Digby. Thanks. I've been thinking on these lines. I'm not sure how the 'Link to document' is determined - I'm referring to what appears on the 'property' tab of the page as the link to the document.  Are you referring to a way you can configure how Umbraco determines this?  As for the useDomainPrefixes = true, I've been trying to set up a separate mobile site on the same Umbraco instance, but using a different hostname, which is why I need to use this.  Sebastiaan (Umbraco) recommends it: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/general/35029-useDomainPrefixes-when-should-it-be-set-to-false

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes caused by setting the domains for the content nodes incorrectly. If you've right clicked and selected "Manage Hostnames" then you can get issues like this.

Remove all hostnames and see if everything works with UseDomainPrefixes=true.

I would reinstall from scratch and rebuild the site if the worst happens and you really cannot fix.