# Umbraco - Incorrect alternative link to document

Tags: hyperlink, umbraco

On our website, we have the following structure:

```
sitename
  -Global
    -English
  -UK
    -English
```

for the Global > English page, the links to the page are showing as:

Link to document

/global/en/

Alternative Links

```
http://english
```

so the 'Link to document' is correct, but the alternative link isn't. On the UK > English page, I just get the correct 'Link to document'.  I've tried publishing out the whole site but I can't as it times out (I've tried increasing all the timeouts, but it's taking an hour to publish so I get a strange network error), and just re-publishing the whole 'Global' node and sub-documents doesn't fix things.  Any other way to fix this?  Also what is the purpose of the 'Alternative Links' and how are these determined?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Hi Digby, no I haven't actually found anything that completely solves the issue.  For what I'm ultimately trying to achieve (safely having different hostnames pointing to different sites on a single Umbraco instance), I can get this working without this issue getting in the way, as long as I keep to <useDomainPrefixes>false</useDomainPrefixes> in the umbracoSettings.config

Answer (score 3):

as I suggested in your original post, I set up a very basic Umbraco v6.1.2 instance (using NuGet in Visual Studio) with a single doc type and an identical top-level structure to what you have described.

So:

1. Set umbracoUseDirectoryUrls to true in the web.config
2. The doc type, called "BasicPage" has a single property called "umbracoUrlName". This allows you to overwrite the path created by Umbraco based upon the title of the node. I assume you already have that in your doc type.
3. I set both English nodes to have a umbracoUrlName of "en".
4. I added two hostnames to the Root node - "localhost" and "mobile.localhost"
5. I published the Root node and all following nodes

[image: Umbraco screenshot]

As you can see, both the "Link to document" and "Alternative links" are as expected.

I suspect you may be right that trying to get the site to publish *may* fix the issue, so you may have to publish the site in bits, working from branch to branch.

However, I would advise creating a test Umbraco instance as I have done and then comparing what you have.

Alternatively, you can of course remove the hostname settings altogether if the entire content structure is going to be served using the same hostnames as these can simply be controlled in IIS. Umbraco doesn't actually need to know about them unless you have separate distinct sites in the same content tree.

Comment: Excellent answer Digby - huge thanks for your effort.  I'll try this out soon, and will mark this as the answer assuming it works out.